# HangFire "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SqlDelegatedTransaction'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, transactions, mono, hangfire

Looking for some help with HangFire in Visual Studio Mac." It is a WebAPI project that works on Windows / IIS.

During startup, HangFire is initialized. Once this happens, we try to set up a recurring job. This is throwing an exception when connected to SQL Server 2014 on Windows OR SQL Server 2019 CTP on Linux.

`{System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: Transaction failed ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SqlDelegatedTransaction'.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.GetValidConnection () [0x0000a]…}`

When connecting to Azure SQL, it returns 

`{System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase (System.Transactions.IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, System.Guid promoterType)`

Tried HangFire 1.6.8 (works on Windows), 1.6.14 and 1.6.21.

Error is thrown when calling `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` or  `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate`.

To simplify this, I implemented as simple function instead of ours, which also fails.

e.g.

`BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.Write("Enqueue"));`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to resolve this... I had to download the source for HangFire, add the projects as references and set the HangFire.SQLServer Project to compile without the "NETFULL" Symbol.